# Angular 6 and Angular material dialog box is not opening after successful add to database inside subscribe method

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material, angular6, angular-material-6

I am trying to open angular material dialog component after a successful insert into database:

```
addHousehold(){
    let last_name_ar = this.formGroup.controls['last_name_ar'].value;

    let last_name_en = this.formGroup.controls['last_name_en'].value;
    .......//Other data
    let arrayOfLegalProtection = this.arrayOfLegalProtection;

    this.showSpinner = true;
    this.auth.addHousehold(this.unit_id,
      ...//Other data
      this.user_id
      ).subscribe(
      (data)=>{
        console.log(data);
        if(data=="enableAdd")
        {
          this.showSpinner = false;
          this.enableDisableAdd = "enableAdd";
          this.formGroup.reset();
          this.arrayOfLegalProtection = [];
          // this.openDialog(data);
          this.openDialog();
        }
        else
        {
          this.showSpinner = true;
          this.enableDisableAdd = "disableAdd";
          this.formGroup.reset();
        }
      },
      (error)=>{
        console.log(error);
      }
    )
}
```

As you can see, I've added the following line into the `(data)` part of `subscribe()` method:

```
this.openDialog();
```

the `openDialog()` has the following code:

```
openDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddIndividualComponent, {
      width: '250px',
      data: {unit_id: this.unit_id}
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
      console.log('The dialog was closed');

    });
}
```

When an insert to database is successful, the dialog does not open, and no errors are shown at the console.

When I move the `this.openDialog()` outside of subscribe method, the dialog opens normally.

I even tried to declare the function from scratch inside the subscribe() but I got an error saying, cannot find `openDialog()`.

How to open the dialog box of angular material after adding into database and receive a successful response ?

Comment: Pls add you dialog component code into question. Also try to console log in dialog comp constructor to see if its getting called.

Comment: It is empty for now, but it is running if I remove it from the subscribe method into `ngOnInit()` per example

Comment: You mean dialog box does open when you open it in `ngOnInit()`?

Comment: Yes. But inside subscribe() method of any httplient response, it doesn't. @User3250

Comment: Strange, and `if(data=="enableAdd")` is `true` right?

Comment: Yes. I can see at the console. But let me check it again tomorrow to be sure.

Comment: Try launching the dialog after the subscribe method by using a timeout: `setTimeout(this.openDialog())`.

Comment: @User3250 you are right, it turned that the data returned is an integer and not a text.

Comment: @G.Tranter I will definitely use a timer even if I knew what was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason for dialog not showing up is that below condition isn't true and hence 'openDialog()' not getting called. Pls check it.

```
if(data=="enableAdd") //not true
```